# React Router: Having one Route conditionally render component based on url search param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here's a scenario example:

I have two components  and

The search params look like this: ?A=123&B=456

The Route is like this path="/home"

I want A to load on the route if only A is present in the search params (e.g. ?A=123), I want B to load if there is B in the search params (B also loads if both A and B are in the search params).

Can I do something inside the Route component where I can have a conditional render based on that and how would I go about doing that?

AKA:

```
<Route
path="/home"
if(urlparam.B){
render={<B/>}
} else {
render={<A/>}
}
</Route>
```

how can I pass the url to the route so it can check?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in the `Route` component, but you can create a wrapper component to handle this.

You can  access the current `location` object's `search` string. From here you can create a `URLSearchParams` object and access the queryString parameters and apply the conditional rendering logic.

- [location](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location)

  Locations represent where the app is now, where you want it to go, or even where it was. It looks like this:

  ```
   {
     key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
     pathname: '/somewhere',
     search: '?some=search-string',
     hash: '#howdy',
     state: {
       [userDefined]: true
     }
   }
  ```
- [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Code

```
const Wrapper = ({ location }) => {
  const { search } = location;
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);

  const hasAParam = searchParams.get("A");
  const hasBParam = searchParams.get("B");

  if (hasAParam && !hasBParam) { // only A and not B
    return <A />;
  } else if (hasBParam) {        // only B
    return <B />;
  }
  return null; // render nothing
};
```

...

```
<Route path="/home" component={Wrapper} />
```

This assumes you are using `react-router-dom@5`.

If using v6, then use the `useSearchParams` hook directly.

[useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams)

Example:

```
const Wrapper = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const hasAParam = searchParams.get("A");
  const hasBParam = searchParams.get("B");

  if (hasAParam && !hasBParam) { // only A and not B
    return <A />;
  } else if (hasBParam) {        // only B
    return <B />;
  }
  return null; // render nothing
};
```

...

```
<Route path="/home" element={<Wrapper />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<Route
path="/home"
render={urlparam?.B ? <B/> : <A/>}
></Route>
```

In this case you can use the ternary operator to solve your problem